# Remove active state from parent when child is clicked and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, addclass, removeclass

I need need a way to get my active state to work properly in my sidebar.

Currently my problems are:

1. When a li is clicked, all children (.sub-menu) receive the active state state.
2. When a li (not sub-menu) is clicked after having clicked a submenu li the active state of the clicked submenu li is not removed.

Hope you can help.

```
$("#sidebar li").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('#sidebar li').children().removeClass('active');
});
```

html

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="sidebar">
    <?php
    if (is_page('gulvservice')){
        wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'gulvservice' ));
    } elseif (is_page('malerservice')) {
        wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'malerservice' ));
    } elseif (is_page('industrilakering')) {
        wp_nav_menu(array('menu'=>'industrilakering' ));
    }
    ?>
    <!-- <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'gulvservice' ) ); ?> -->
    <div class="gulvservice-kontaktinfo">
        <p>EM. Meyers Eftf. A/S</p>
        <p>CVR: 82510028</p>
        <p>Tlf.: 36349500 / 40384053</p>
        <p>E-mail: gulve@meyers.dk</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

rendered html:

[image]

Comment: Post you HTML code please.

Comment: Didn't think it would be neccesary, but sure.

Comment: I think it's not the correct HTML @Jonas since i cant see `ul` and `li`s.

Comment: wp_nav_menu outputs all that stuff. Can you post rendered HTML from inspector for reference?

Comment: It is dynamically created by wordpress. I cannot copy paste from the site, but i have taken a screenshot.

I have a hard time seeing how it matters though.

Comment: You could copy it from browser inspector (select ul and click F2 then copy).

Comment: What about using `$('#sidebar li').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active');`? That will clear ALL `<li>` elements of the active class, and will just add it to the currently clicked `<li>`...

Comment: Oh thanks Zakaria, didn't know that.

Comment: @mark.hch it works for the 2nd problem stated in the OP, but not the first. Thanks though, simple solution for the 2nd problem.

Comment: So if you click a `<li>` in the `.sub-menu`, do you want that `<li>` to receive active or the parent `<li>`? I'm a little confused about "all children receive the active state state"...

Comment: Currently when an `<li>` from the parent list is pressed, all its children receives an active state. I want it so it is only the parent `<li>`receiving the active state when it is pressed.

When an `<li>`in the submenu is pressed, i want that exact `<li>`to receive the hover state and remove it from any others.

[Picture](http://puu.sh/nlrq2/7a758fd076.png) for reference.

Comment: I don't see how the children would currently be receiving the active class, you are only adding it to the individual `<li>` that was clicked. I think your issue might be stemming from the CSS. Are you applying background-color using a CSS selector like `#sidebar li.active`, because default background-color is transparent, so the child items would have that same color... you could use `#sidebar li.active ul` to set the background-color of children of a selected item to the non-active color...

Comment: `ul li:hover, .active{ background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);}` is all the css i have to show for it. But i will try and look a it into it.

Comment: I just tried your solution by setting the background color of the children of the active parent to transparent, but it did not work, although i could see the logic behind it.

Comment: @mark.hch i think i found the problem. However i am not sure how to fix it. The problem is that the initial `li` contains the `.sub-menu` items, which means that the background color from the initial list item is shown behind the new transparent sub menu items making them appear active.

I could just set the background color of all the sub-menu list items with no active state to the the background color of the side-menu, the problem however is that i'm using a gradient.

Comment: That's what I was getting at, but I can see the gradient being an issue... You may be better off changing it to a solid color - that kind of stinks. If you could modify the WP code that outputs this, you could make the `.sub-menu` a direct child of the `#sidebar`, which could help you keep your gradient... but as it stands now, I'm unsure. Here's a demo if you could move your `.sub-menu` to be a child of `#sidebar`, but I doubt you'll want to go that route, as it'll probably affect other portions of the code - https://jsfiddle.net/L01436t0/.

Comment: @mark.hch i just made it work, but in a bit unusual way. I achieved it using pseudo elements instead. Will answer the question with my solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Found solutions to both problems.

1:

I achieved this using pseudo elements through css instead of jquery.
The reason i made some :before elements was due to some indentation on my sub-menu list items.

CSS:

```
#sidebar ul li{
    text-align: left;
    padding-left:25px;
    position:relative;
}

#sidebar ul li a{
text-decoration: none;
color:white;
text-align:left;
position:relative;
z-index:100000;
}


#sidebar ul li:hover:after:not(.submenu){
    content: "";
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:100;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#sidebar ul li.active:after{
    content: "";
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:100;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#sidebar ul li ul li:hover:after{
    content: "";
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    padding-left:25px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:100;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}


#sidebar ul li ul li:hover:before{
    content: "";
    width:25px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-25px;
    z-index:100;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#sidebar ul li ul li.active:after{
    content: "";
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    padding-left:25px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:;
    z-index:100;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#sidebar ul li ul li.active:before{
    content: "";
    width:25px;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:-25px;
    z-index:100;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}
```

2: Credit goes to @mark.hch

First remove active class from all list items.
Next add active class to the clicked list item.

```
$('#sidebar li').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```